# Counting the number of asymmetric graphs on n nodes?

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

Asymmetric graph is a graph that has only trivial automorphism. Asymptotically, almost all finite graphs are asymmetric.  I'm looking for upper bounds and lower bounds on the growth rate of the number of asymmetric graphs on n nodes.

Also, I'm looking for a function $f(n)$ that exactly counts the number of asymmetric graph on n nodes? Is this function efficiently computable?

Comment: Sure it's computable: there are finitely many graphs on n nodes and a terminating algorithm for determining whether or not they are asymmetric.  Whether it's _efficiently_ computable...

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at the references in [A003400](http://oeis.org/A003400) for possibly disconnected graphs and [A124059](http://oeis.org/A124059) for connected ones.  Neither gives a formula, even asymptotic.

Comment: Thanks Ross, It seems that the growth rate must be bounded from below by exponential function.

Comment: It seems likely that you are right that most graphs are asymmetric.  And on $n$ nodes there are $2^{n(n-1)/2}$  total graphs.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ross, I wonder why such a natural problem has not got enough attention.